# Proof of Cauchy's theorem for punctured domains.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am unable to prove the following lemma of Cauchy's integral theorem for simple closed curve.

> **Lemma**: Let $R$ be a simply connected region. If $f(z)$ be analytic in $R-\{a\}$ and is continuous on $R$ then for all simple closed curves $\gamma$ in $R$ $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$$

This result really surprised me a lot! Because the point $a$ may lies on $\gamma$ or inside $\gamma$ (If it lies outside $\gamma$ then it is obvious that, integral evaluates to zero due to 'Cauchy's integral theorem for simple closed curve')

However, I have still manged to prove this lemma for the case of triangle. That is when $\gamma$ is parametrized boundary of a triangle contained in $R$.
So from this, certainly I can extend this proof for the case of any closed polygon.

But, I am unable to extend it for the case of any simple closed curve(due to the point $a$ where $f$ is not analytic)

Moreover, I like to know, what if the function $f(z)$ is not analytic at more than one points? Though it continuous at those points. (I mean, can we **extend** this lemma?)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of establishing this -- the approach taken, for example, by Rudin in his book Real and Complex Analysis -- is to prove the following version of Cauchy's theorem for a triangle

**Theorem**: Let $D$ be a domain (connected open subset) of $\mathbb C$ and let $f \colon D\backslash \{a\} \to \mathbb C$ be a function defined on all but one point of $D$, and assume that $f$ is holmorphic on $D\backslash\{a\}$ and that there is an $r>0$ such that $|f(z)|\leq C_a$ for all $z\in B(a,r)\backslash\{a\}$ where $C_a$ is some positive constant. Then if $T$ is any closed triangular path in $D$,

$$
\int_T f(z)dz =0,
$$
whether or not $a$ lies on the path or in its interior.

*Proof*: One can deduce this fairly easily from the theorem for a triangle where the domain does not contain any ``bad'' points: First one can reduce to the case where $a$ is a vertex of the triangle -- if $a$ is not on the path or in its interior, then the claim follows from the standard result for a triangle. If $a$ lies in the closed region bounded by the triangle, then one first reduces to the case where $a$ is a vertex of the triangle: If $a$ is not already a vertex, join $a$ to all three vertices of the triangle. This will divide the original triangle into three sub-triangles (or two, if $a$ is located on one of the edges of the triangle).

[image: Reduction step and bounding the integral]

For the case where $a$ is a vertex of the triangle $T$ and label the other two vertices $b$ and $c$, so that for clarity we may write $T(abc)$ in place of $T$. Now introduce points $d$ and $e$ on the edges $ab$ and $ac$ respectively, both very close to $a$. Then

$$
\begin{split}
\int_{T[abc]} f(z)dz &= \int_{T(dae)} f(z)dz + \int_{T(dbe)} f(z)dz + \int_{T(dcb)}\\
&= \int_{T(dae)}f(z)dz
\end{split}
$$
where in going from the first to the second line we used the fact that the last two integrals on the right-hand side of the first line vanish by the ordinary version of Cauchy's theorem for a triangle. (See the attached figure)

But then it follows that
$$
0\leq |\int_{T(abc)} f(z)dz| = |\int_{T(dae)} f(z)dz| \leq \ell(T(dae)).C_a
$$
and since $\ell(T(dae)) \to 0$ as $d,e \to a$, it follows that $\int_{T(abc)} f(z)dz=0$ as required.

Once you have this result, by induction the result holds for a function with finitely many "bad points". Moreover, the proof of Cauchy's theorem for a convex domain immediately goes through to the case with ``bad points'', and similarly one deduces Cauchy's Integral Formula. (This is the reason Rudin proves the "bad point" version of the result -- if you want to prove the integral formula, it is natural to consider the function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$. If $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $D$, then $g(z)$ is also, except perhaps at $z=z_0$, where one only knows $g$ is continuous. If you can still apply Cauchy's theorem for a disk to such functions, the integral formula follows immediately.

To give a bit more detail: we say that $S$ is a star-shaped domain in the complex plane, if there is a point $s_0 \in S$ with the property that the line segment joining it to any other point in $S$ lies entirely inside $S$. (Thus a convex set is start-shaped with respect to any of its points for example). For such a domain, given a function $f$ with the property that its integral around any triangle is zero, the function $F(w) = \int_{[s_0,w]} f(z)dz$ where $[s_0,w]$ is the path $t \mapsto (1-t)s_0 +tw$. Indeed $F(w+h)-F(w)= \int_{[w,w+h]} f(z)dz$ because the integral of $f$ around the triangle with vertices $s_0,w$ and $w+h$ is zero. It is then easy to see that $F'(w)=f(w)$. But then for any closed contour in the star-like domain, $\int_\gamma f(z)dz =0$, since it is the difference in values of the primitive at the start and end points of the path, which for a closed path are the same.

But Cauchy's Integral Formula (for a  disk say) readily shows that a holomorphic function is equal to its Taylor series, and since one now has the Integral Formula for any function which is holomorphic except perhaps at one point, it follows that any such function is equal to its Taylor series, and hence is differentiable (and in fact infinitely differentiable).

Note that because $\mathbb C$ is locally convex, we do not need Cauchy's theorem for a simply-connected domain at all, since it suffices to show that the restriction of $f$ to a disk containing $a$ is holomorphic everywhere in that disk in order to deduce that $f$ was in fact differentiable on the entire simply-connected domain. Indeed if $R$ is a simply-connected region and $f$ is holomorphic function defined on $R\backslash S$ where $S$ is a discrete subset if $R$ (that is, the subspace topology on $S$ is the discrete topology) with $f$ bounded near each element of $S$, then $f$ extends uniquely to a holomorphic function on all or $R$.

*Update*: A variant of the above approach would be to use a Morera-type result: If  $f\colon D \to \mathbb C$ is a function (where $D$ is a domain in $\mathbb C$), and $\int_T f(z)dz=0$ for all triangles in $D$, then if we fix $z_0 \in D$ and pick an open disk $B(z_0,r)\subseteq D$, then $f$ has a primitive in the disk $B(z_0,r)$ (that is, there is a function $F \colon B(z_0,r) \to \mathbb C$ such that $F'=f$. But since $F$ is differentiable, it is analytic and hence infinitely differentiable, so that, in particular, $f$ is differentiable.

Thus it follows that if $f$ is holomorphic except perhaps at one point, nearby which it is bounded, to show that $f$ is in fact holomorphic everywhere it suffices to show that $\int_T f(z)dz=0$ for all triangles $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sir, as I said in the post I have proved the result for the case of a triangles. But unable to extend the proof for, "Cauchy's theorem for the convex domain with one bad point" and as well as not able to deduce the Cauchy's integral formula for such a case.

Comment: Further, in the variant approach where you suggested to use Morera's theorem. Yes we are given that, $f(z)$ is continuous in a simply connected region $R$ but we are not given that, $\int_\gamma f(z) dz=0$ **for every** simple closed curve in $R$. So how could we apply Morera's theorem? (We just know that, integral equals to zero for the case of a triangles but Morera's theorem requirement is that, this integral must be equals to zero around every simple closed curve in $R$)

Comment: The point is that because differentiability is a local property, you only need triangle paths: If you know that $\int_T f(z)dz=0$ for all triangles in a domain $D$, where $f\colon D \to \mathbb C$, then on any disk $B(a,r) \subseteq D$, or indeed on any star-shaped subset of $D$, the function $f$ has a primitive, and hence is itself differentiable. But if $f$ is differentiable on every disk contained in $D$ it is certainly differentiable on D.

Comment: Added some more detail about the Morera approach, and details about Cauchy's Integral Formula etc. which I hope help clarify the ideas required. If one has a function with a bad point, you just want to show that the function must in fact be holomorphic there, and then quote the standard version of Cauchy's theorem for whatever type of domain you need, and showing the bad point is removable only requires working with disks.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is in the interior of $R$ then by the removable singularity theorem, since $f$ will be continuous on some compact disc about $a$, $f$ is analytic at $a$. If $a$ is in the boundary of $R$, then all we know is that $f$ is analytic on the interior of $R$ and continuous on its boundary ... but wait! Coupled with simple-connectivity of $R$, this is exactly the situation where Cauchy's theorem applies.

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate little bit more. Specially about removable singularity theorem. (Moreover, I didn't downvoted the answer)

Comment: @GeneralMathematics For simplicity say $D$ is the unit disc and $a=0$. If $f$ is analytic everywhere in the unit disc except possibly at zero, it has a Laurent expansion there. $f$ is analytic at zero iff. the negative exponents of its expansion are all zero iff. $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ exists (and is finite). But this is true, since $f$ is continuous at zero. Therefore $f$ is analytic on the whole disc

Comment: Sir, thanks for replying. Sir, in the text book that I am using, definition of analytic function is, "a function $f(z)$ is said to be analytic at point $z_0$ if there exists a neighborhood of $z_0$ at all points of which $f'(z)$ exists. Can you please try to explain me with the help of this definition.

Comment: @GeneralMathematics I have one perspective on this. [Here](https://www.math.uci.edu/~brusso/220C040908.pdf) is another; Riemann’s theorem applies because $(z-a)f(z)\to0\cdot f(a)=0$ by continuity of $f$ at $a$

Comment: A nice way to see the removable singularity theorem is as follows: if $f\colon D\backslash \{z_0\} \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and bounded near $z_0$, then $\lim_{z \to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=0$, and so $(z-z_0)^2f(z)$ is actually holomorphic on all of $D$. (At points $w \neq z_0$ this is easy, since $(z-z_0)^2$ and $f(z)$ are, and at $z=z_0$, $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z) = 0$ as $f(z)$ is bounded near $z_0$. But then $g(z)$ is holomorphic on all of $D$ and vanishes to order (at least) 2 at $z_0$, and hence $f(z)= g(z)/(z-z_0)^2$ is holomorphic at $z_0$.